# Sample .ics subscription to MAC iCalender is working well but this is not working when we push iCalander to iCloud and iCloud to iPhone iCal

Tags: asp.net, icloud, icalendar

I am having problem in subscribe .ics file on iPhone using iCloud. I have one application in which we are generating .ics file for user’s event.

The link of .ics file http://www.wealthadvisorcrm.com/sampleical.ics is working well when I subscribe it to iCalander on MAC Machine. But when I subscribe it using iCloud with iphone that it is not working. What is the issue on iphone or where is the issue in my .ics file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use webcal protocol, this is working on iPhone, iPad etc.

```
webcal://wealthadvisorcrm.com/sampleical.ics
```

[For more source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603866/what-is-a-webcal-protocol)

Comment: Worked very well.! Thanks For your time.