# How does one write a link to multiple ICS files?

Tags: html, icalendar

If a user has a Calendar Subscription page that users can choose which calendars to subscribe to, and wanted to provide a single link that gave them the option to subscribe (download all) the .ICS files, how would one write that link (php, html, javascript supported) as both desktop and mobile friendly?

I've found that if you use http://linkto.ics the calendar will import; while if you use webcal://linkto.ics the calendar will attempt to open in a calendar. Using the webcal protocol seems to be the route to go.

I've seen the workflow, I just don't know how it was achieved: the Subscribe to All link was clicked, then you were prompted with "Would you like to Subscribe to X calendar? Yes No"... then another prompt for "Would you like to Subscribe to Y calendar? Yes No"... and so on until all the calendars in the list were subscribed. It was almost like a loop of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

please note that 'subscribing' is quite different from downloading and importing.
Download and import is a one off - the calendars will not update.  The imported events will go into whatever calendar the user chooses once.

Subscribing keeps the new calendars separate. The application will check for updates to those links every now and then.  For this reason it is not really possible to combine the calendars unless you use a third party tool/website that will check the underlying calendars at regular intervals for updates and issue a new ics link that combines the incoming ics files (ie merges the events into one file).

Note that even though all events (VEVENTS) have unique identifers, that doesn't mean that applications can check for updates by event.  Applications use the url of the ics file to check for updates and only when the ics url has been subscribed to.

Comment: Is this true even with the webcal protocol? I have revised my question to clarify the scenario.

Comment: Yes webcal is just an unofficial way to format a calendar url.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603866/what-is-a-webcal-protocol  It still refers to an ics file which has to meet rfc5545 standards