# Automating subscription to iCalendar (RFC5545) feed

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I maintain an RFC5545 calendar for my school and I'd like to simplify the subscription process. I'm wondering if it is possible to create a URL or something similar that would facilitate calendar discovery and subscription. Ultimately what I'd like is a "click here to subscribe" link. Ideally for Outlook, but macOS Calendar (iCal), and Google Calendar would also be nice to support.

Is this possible? So far my Google foo is failing me and I'm only finding instructions for manually adding a calendar subscription, nothing for how to automate the process for my users.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the a calendar example with a URI using the [webcal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcal) protocol. There is a bit more information in this post: [What is a webcal protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603866/what-is-a-webcal-protocol). The URI would be constructed like this:

`webcal://calendar.example.com/calendar.ics`

A user who clicks on the link is prompted to open their calendaring app and add subscribe to the calendar. It works for iOS and macOS Calendar and Outlook.